# Is /usr being touched before /etc/fstab-specified volumes get mounted?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I have extracted /usr to a LVM volume that gets mounted by /etc/fstab on an Ubuntu 12.04 box.
Basically I ran out of space on / mountpoint and LVM wasn't installed when I got the box, so /dev/sda1 is mounted on /.

But I'm worried that there could be issues when I reboot the box there could be issues, in case some binary within /usr would be called before volumes from /etc/fstab would be mounted.

Do you guys have any insight on if this could possibly happen? And am I boned in that case?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Linux filesystem hierarchy](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html) `/usr` *should* contain "user land" applications and not the system essentials required for booting the system; it may even be a shared directory e.g. over NFS.

Binaries that are required for booting before /usr is mounted are supposed to all be contained within /bin, /sbin, and /lib.

Comment: Thank you sir! What made me think is that things like sudo are apparently located within /usr/bin, so I wasnt sure anymore on if there would be other maybe-critical stuff in there..